# iphone: business card reader sdk apart from ABBY

Tags: iphone, ocr

I am doing an app in which I require a business card reader I googled alot but BBY is the only solution which I was able to find out. Can anybody help me out with some opensource library which can be tweaked or used directly as a business card reader.

Please enlighten me on this.

Answer (score 1):

you can look into the Tesseract open source engine... its pretty good for image processing.. i mean it will extract the text out of the image but then you will have to process it to extract name ,phone numbers and other details.
this guy has explained how to use it in iOS .. http://tinsuke.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-compile-and-use-tesseract-3-01-on-ios-sdk-5/

Answer (score 0):

We started an open source project to build a Javascript library (based on the OCR engine [tesseract.js](http://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/) for the OCR part) that exctract the relevant data from a business card based on heuristic criteria.

The library ([BCR Library](https://github.com/syneo-tools-gmbh/Javascript-BCR-Library), available on github) is usable in any html project (included mobile cordova, phone gap or ionic projects) just including it via script tag.

The library doesn't have any external api call and fully works offline.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should give a try to [Covve Bussiness Card Scan API](https://covve.com/business-card-scanning-api/). The quality of the result is great in various languages. You can check a comparison analysis of similar services [here](https://www.capacitorpartners.com/post/an-extensive-comparison-of-business-card-scanners-camcard-abbyy-covve-scan-bizconnect).

[Disclosure] I'm part of the team developing the service.