# Parse data from image?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iphone: business card reader sdk apart from ABBY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865621/iphone-business-card-reader-sdk-apart-from-abby)

I was wondering how I would go about parsing an image in iOS to get data out of it?
For example say a user was about to take a picture of a business card, how would I add the logic to the program to automatically take the photo once the user centers it in a displayed red box? Would there be any way to read what the business card said and convert it to text?

A simple Google searh didn't turn anything up.

Comment: Search for OCR (Optical Character Recognition) to find info on how to turn an image of text to usable text. You'll find things like these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538608/getting-text-from-image-on-ios-image-processing

Comment: But what about if I wanted to add logic to make the camera take a capture once the business card is fully taking up the red box as described above?

Comment: You're talking about stuff that you're not going to get a simple answer to in SO -- it's stuff that will require substantial research on your part.

Comment: But you can start on the [Signal Processing SO site](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/), and there's probably a graphics forum site around somewhere.

Comment: The above-linked question is just one of many here on the topic of business card scanning alone: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+%2Bbusiness+%2Bcard , so I'd recommend starting with the resources listed in these.